# How to store multiple descriptors, from different images, in a vector of vectors in C++ and OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, initialization, histogram

I'm using OpenCV to evaluate some algorithms for face recognition, at the moment I'm using HoG ( Histogram of Oriented Gradients)

I wish to store descriptors, from several images, in a vector, for later comparison.

For each image it stores X descriptors in a vector of floats usually initialized like this:

```
vector <float> descriptors;
```

So, in order to store many, I thought the initialization would be something like this:

```
vector <vector <float> > descriptors;
```

Although the program compiles ok, it stops at `hog.compute`  without any warning or error.

```
for (i = 0; i < images.size(); i++){

    hog.compute(images[i], descriptors[i], Size(16,16), Size(4,4), locs);

}
```

Any tip or suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is `hog.compute` defined? And what do you mean by "stops"?

Comment: Did you think of filling `descriptors` with N empty `vector<float>` (where N is the number of images), before the for loop ?

Comment: Thank you MikeMB, in fact the problem was in space allocation :) By "stop" I meant that the program just crash without any information. 
Indeed @AldurDisciple, was precisely that as herohuyongtao described!
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allocate enough space for `descriptors` before calling it. There's only a empty container by `vector <vector <float> > descriptors;`, it will crash if you trying to access its elements, i.e. `descriptors[0]`, because `descriptors.size()==0` currently.

You can simply change

```
vector <vector <float> > descriptors;
```

to

```
vector <vector <float> > descriptors(images.size());
```

or

```
vector <vector <float> > descriptors;
descriptors.resize(images.size());
```